# javascript variable not available to HTML part

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am beginner to Web dev and learning AngularJS. I am trying some assignment and encountered the problem that variable defined in a function (Angular controller) is not getting accessed in HTML and shows nothing when opened in browser. The link is: https://jsfiddle.net/2v41a6na/

Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController" >
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="media">
                    <div class="media-left media-middle">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                            <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                            <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                        </h2>
                        <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--<p>Put the dish details here</p>-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-1">
                <p>Put the comments here</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);
        
        app.controller('dishDetailController', function() {

            var dish={
                          name:'Uthapizza',
                          image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                          category: 'mains', 
                          label:'Hot',
                          price:'4.99',
                          description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comments: [
                               {
                                   rating:5,
                                   comment:"Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
                                   author:"John Lemon",
                                   date:"2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
                                   author:"Paul McVites",
                                   date:"2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:3,
                                   comment:"Eat it, just eat it!",
                                   author:"Michael Jaikishan",
                                   date:"2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:4,
                                   comment:"Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
                                   author:"Ringo Starry",
                                   date:"2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               },
                               {
                                   rating:2,
                                   comment:"It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
                                   author:"25 Cent",
                                   date:"2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
                               }
                               
                           ]
                    };
            
            this.dish = dish;
            
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The intended design should be like [image]

***EDIT 1:*** I did not use `$scope` above.
I have similar code, which works perfectly but with different design. Code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="confusionApp">

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head
         content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: Menu</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/mystyles.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(1)}"><a ng-click="menuCtrl.select(1)" aria-controls="all menu" role="tab"> The Menu</a> </li>
                    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(2)}"><a ng-click="menuCtrl.select(2)" aria-controls="appetizers" role="tab"> Appetizers</a> </li>
                    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(3)}"><a ng-click="menuCtrl.select(3)" aria-controls="mains" role="tab"> Mains</a> </li>
                    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:menuCtrl.isSelected(4)}"><a ng-click="menuCtrl.select(4)" aria-controls="desserts" role="tab"> Desserts</a> </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <ul class="media-list tab-pane fade in active">
                        <li class="media" ng-repeat="dish in menuCtrl.dishes | filter:menuCtrl.filtText">
                            <div class="media-left media-middle">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img class="media-object img-thumbnail" ng-src={{dish.image}} alt="Uthappizza">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h2 class="media-heading">{{dish.name}}
                                    <span class="label label-danger">{{dish.label}}</span>
                                    <span class="badge">{{dish.price | currency}}</span>
                                </h2>
                                <p>{{dish.description}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('confusionApp',[]);
        app.controller('menuController', function(){
             this.tab =1;
             var dishes=[
                         {
                           name:'Uthapizza',
                           image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                           category: 'mains',
                           label:'Hot',
                           price:'4.99',
                           description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
                           comment: ''
                        },
                        {
                           name:'Zucchipakoda',
                           image: 'images/zucchipakoda.png',
                           category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'',
                           price:'1.99',
                           description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
                           comment: ''
                        },
                        {
                           name:'Vadonut',
                           image: 'images/vadonut.png',
                           category: 'appetizer',
                           label:'New',
                           price:'1.99',
                           description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
                           comment: ''
                        },
                        {
                           name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                           image: 'images/elaicheesecake.png',
                           category: 'dessert',
                           label:'',
                           price:'2.99',
                           description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
                           comment: ''
                        }
                        ];
            this.dishes= dishes;
            this.filtText= '';
            
            this.select = function(setTab){
                this.tab = setTab;
                if(setTab==2)
                    this.filtText= 'appetizer';
                else if (setTab==3)
                    this.filtText= 'mains';
                else if (setTab ==4)
                    this.filtText = 'dessert';
                else
                    this.filtText = '';
            }
            this.isSelected = function(checkTab){
                return (this.tab == checkTab);
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Outpur for the above code is: [image]

Now I am unable to understand why this one works but not first one. Both of them do not use `$scope`.

Comment: Have you defined that varible in $scope?

Comment: Like Halter said, $scope is the object that lets you use javascript variables through HTML. Everything you bind to your scope will be available in the view. So not all variables should be bound to the scope. For example: if you have some logic which uses variables. You shouldn't bind them to the scope, but rather use them the old fashion way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to declare it in `$scope`. The second example uses angular's `controller as` syntax, in which the variables and methods are bound directly into the returned controller. You have the `ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl"`, and so the list of dishes is the value of `menuCtrl.dishes`.

In your first example, you're not using the `controller as` syntax. You either need to do it by using for example `ng-controller="dishDetailController as detailCtrl"` so you can access your dish variable with `detailCtrl.dish`, or then as others have said, you can use `ng-controller="dishDetailController"` and then in your controller `$scope.dish = dish`.

EDIT: More information here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController#example

Comment: Good catch, is one a better practice than the other? I've always used scope.

Comment: Check my edit, they explain it pretty clearly there. Personally I prefer the `controller as` syntax, since it makes it very explicit which controller's variables you're accessing. For example, if you had a controller inside another controller, with the `$scope` approach you could only access the inner controller's variables in the inner HTML, but with `controller as` you can access either.

Answer (score 1):

Two things

1) declare ng-app in HTML as

```
 <div class="container" ng-app="confusionApp">
```

2) and use $scope in controller like

```
 app.controller('dishDetailController', function($scope) {

        $scope.dish={
                      name:'Uthapizza',
                      image: 'images/uthapizza.png',
                      category: 'mains', 
                      label:'Hot'
        }
 });
```

Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2v41a6na/1/

**Update**

It worked due to this line in HTML

```
 <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl">
```

Even your code will work just you have declare your controller in HTML like

```
 <div class="row row-content" ng-controller="dishDetailController as dishes" >
```

and replace all dish with dishes.dish

```
 <h2 class="media-heading">{{dishes.dish.name}}
                        <span class="label label-danger">{{dishes.dish.label}}</span>
```

Working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/2v41a6na/3/

Comment: Thats great. Can you please see EDIT1 in question and tell me how that works?

Comment: it worked due to ng-controller="menuController as menuCtrl this

Comment: using menuCtrl he access variables present inside the controller